# Reproducible go binaries on aws codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-codebuild

I use codebuild to create a go binary using go 1.14.7 on linux:

`GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -trimpath -ldflags=-buildid="" -o myBin main.go`

I check the hash of the binary each run (`shasum256 myBin`) and it's always different.  I see codebuild sets a unique GOPATH for each run.  I'm using mod but in case it could affect the binary I set it to `/go` (seems impossible to unset).  Locally I have downloaded the different source zips used by codebuild, the build path is different each time but locally, in each of the downloaded sources I'm able to build the binary and the hashes match.

On codebuild though the hash is different on every run.  What might be causing the binary to always have a unique hash?

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't have `CGO_ENABLED=0`  then your binary most likely is linking to something that varies on every platform. Try setting `CGO_ENABLED=0` on both the server build and the local one and see if that makes your hashes match.

Comment: That's the one.  Thanks kindly